# Why tokio::spawn doesn't execute my code?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, spawn, rust-tokio

My rust code is like below.

```
#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    for i in 1..10 {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            println!("{}", i);
        });
    }
}
```

When run the code, I expect it to print 1 to 10 in a random sequence.
But it just print some random numbers:

> 1
> 3
> 2
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Why this is happenning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html warns that:

> There is no guarantee that a spawned task will execute to completion. When a runtime is shutdown, all outstanding tasks are dropped, regardless of the lifecycle of that task.

One solution that should work is to store all of the [`JoinHandle`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html)s and then `await` all of them:

```
let mut join_handles = Vec::with_capacity(10);

for i in 1..10 {
    join_handles.push(tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("{}", i);
    }));
}

for join_handle in join_handles {
    join_handle.await.unwrap();
}
```

P.S. In `1..10`, the end is exclusive, so the last number is 9. You might want `1..=10` instead. (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/range-expr.html)